# How can we get HttpServletRequest(DefaultGlobalContext) for GraphQL from RequestContextHolder for GraphQL (using graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-spqr, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

I'm using `graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter` library to migrate the existing Rest API project to GraphQL. I have a below piece of code to fetch the current `HttpServletRequest` from `RequestContextHolder` for Rest API:

```
 HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
        .currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

However, this returns null for GraphQL. I believe that is correct because for GraphQL we have to use `DefaultGlobalContext<ServletWebRequest>` and not `HttpServletRequest`. But I'm not sure how can we do that.

But, I tried below piece of code:

```
RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
return (HttpServletRequest) requestAttributes.resolveReference(RequestAttributes.REFERENCE_REQUEST);
```

But it didn't work - `requestAttributes` returns null.

I'm very new to GraphQL, could anyone please help me know how can I get HttpServletRequest (DefaultGlobalContext) for GraphQL? This will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It goes like this:

```java
@GraphQLMutation
public void whateverMutation(@GraphQLRootContext DefaultGlobalContext<NativeWebRequest> ctx) {
    HttpServletRequest req = ctx.getNativeRequest().getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse res = ctx.getNativeRequest().getNativeResponse(HttpServletResponse.class);
    ...
}
```